# How to shorten nested if statement

Tags: c#

How can I shorten this nested if statement?

```
if(x > 0){
  if(grid[x-pixelOffset,y] == true){
    middleLeft = 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `&&` operator:

```
if ((x > 0) && grid[x-pixelOffset,y]) 
    ...
```

You do not need `== true` when you check values of `bool` variables.

Comment: && will short-circuit the if evaluation, so you do not risk trying to access a negative array index in grid.

Comment: By doing (x > 0) means it will be evaluated first and than perform the &&. Am I correct? Or does it not matter?

Comment: You are correct, JealousKnight. That's what Eric J. means by "short circuit." If x > 0 fails, it won't even do the second part of the if statement.

Answer (score 2):

Just for more information, if short-circuit is not desired, you may use the &. If you write if( (x>0) & grid[x,y]) {...}, the second part will be evaluated too.